# SCSS Language Injection in Pycharm

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm trying to write a language injection for PyCharm that will recognize anything within a `<style type="text/x-scss"></style>` tag as SCSS. Through some inspection of IntelliJ and the PSI documentation, and direct editing of the IntelliLang.xml file, this is the closest I've gotten:

```java
+ xmlTag().withChild(xmlAttribute().withLocalName(string().equalTo("type")).withValue(string().equalTo("text/x-scss"))).withNamespace(string().equalTo("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"))
```

However, this (a) seems not to do anything, and (b) as soon as I close the Language Injections Pane, PyCharm rewrites the Java as `xmlTag().withLocalName(string().matches("<none>"))`.  What's the right way to do this and to get it to save?

Comment: Do you find out how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a built-in way to do this with SASS specifically.

[Language Injection in WebStorm (scss into html)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329300/language-injection-in-webstorm-scss-into-html)

Simply have your tag look like this:

```
<style rel="stylesheet/scss" type="text/css">
```

In our case, we use Django compressor, so this works fine as well:

```
<style rel="stylesheet/scss" type="text/x-scss">
```