# Language Injection in WebStorm (scss into html)

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, vue.js, jetbrains-ide

**The question:** How to make WebStorm to understand `scss` in `html`

**Description:**

I'm have existed project based on [vue.js](https://vuejs.org)

I've associate `.vue` with `html` language (`.vue` == `.html`).

In general `*.vue` files have structure like:

```
<template>
 ... 
</template>

<script>
  ...
</script>

    <style lang="scss">
      $some_var: 10px;

      .parent_class {
        .child_class {
          padding: $some_var;
        }
       }
    </style>
```

The problem is that WebStorm didn't expect to see `scss` (instead of pure `css`) in html.

I know that "WebStorm" (as well as "IDEA") has `language injection`.
But it's a bit challenging for me to understand how to use language injection properly.

**UPD:** look likes it's may be impossible for now because `scss` is template language (mean not injectable for a while): https://stackoverflow.com/a/29062183/930170

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532082/scss-language-injection-in-pycharm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [supported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14762) in PhpStorm/WebStorm 2016.1 -- for both LESS and SCSS.

But you have to use slightly different syntax: `<style rel="stylesheet/scss" type="text/css">`

```
<style rel="stylesheet/scss" type="text/css">
  $some_var: 10px;

  .parent_class {
    .child_class {
      padding: $some_var;
    }
   }
</style>
```

---

Nuance is: `rel` attribute is not really allowed here. For more standards-complaint approach please watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20921 ticket and star/vote/comment it to get notified on any progress. **UPDATE** -- implemented as of 2017.1 version.

---

**UPDATE 28/03/2017** for 2017.1 version of the IDE

```
<style type="text/scss">
  $some_var: 10px;

  .parent_class {
    .child_class {
      padding: $some_var;
    }
   }
</style>

<style type="text/stylus">
  body
    font: 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif

  a.button
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px
    -moz-border-radius: 5px
    border-radius: 5px
</style>
```

Here how it looks in PhpStorm/WebStorm 2017.1:

[image]

Comment: Is this support gone in 2017.1 EAP?

Comment: Doesn't work in my IDE, not sure why. it used to work  before. http://imgur.com/a/WrP85

Comment: @sha256 Have a look at my screenshot and code sample -- please pay attention to the `type` attribute.