# PhpStorm: Add Sass/SCSS section in HTML

Tags: html, sass, styles, phpstorm

I want to mix HTML and SCSS/Sass in one file. Is there a way to make PhpStorm to respect both languages?

Something like this:

```html
<html>
<h1>a Header</h1>
<p>some text</p>
<style lang="scss">
h1 {
 color: red;
 span {
   color: green;
  }
}
</style>
</html>
```

Is there a way to make PhpStorm to format such a thing correct?

Comment: Sure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36331588/783119 (works since 2017.1 version) -- use `<style type="text/scss">`. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
<style type="text/scss">
        h1 {
            color: red;
        span {
            color: green;
        }
        }
</style>
```

should do the thing; but note that SCSS will not run in a browser without first being compiled to CSS.

Comment: A great solution - works like a ccharme.
Thanks for the hint. my scss is extracted and processed by posthtml.